# How to set values to customer screen in CP20 POS Machine in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, pos

I have developed a Swing application that can be run on the POS machine, but I need to know how to show customer order total price in the Customer Display unit in that CP20 pos machine.

Comment: I'm assuming this means you're running two displays?  You can use [`GraphicsEnvironment`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html) to get a list of `GraphicsDevice`, which will provide you with the screen bounds

Comment: http://itgenius.lk/shop/pos-hardware-accessories/15-capacitive-touch-dual-display-pos-system/ im using this POS machine and I need to display my total amount in that small customer screen.